# How to enable PostgreSQL in a rails app with termux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, termux, termux-linux

I'm trying create a app with ruby on rails in termux, I already installed the necessary gems and packages for the setup, but when doing `rails db:create`.  I get this error

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: connection to server on socket "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server on socket "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: The nature of the error message suggests that postgresql is not running or has an outdated PID within that virtual environment.  If you started it at some point in the past and then disconnected, then returned, it's possible that postgres has hung / terminated.

You should be able to tmux attach and then `psql $whatever_your_database_is_called` and if you get an error you'll know that it's not to do with rails but postgres

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a PostgreSQL server manually for your app to be able to connect to.

Install postgresql via `pkg install postgresql`

See the wiki for sample setup instructions https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Postgresql